# Props value not showing on top of render to a function ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

However the `this.props.NotesAll` retrieving object from another component and it's showing object's to under render() method but when I'm trying to use that `this.props.NotesAll` on top of render on a function to working with those object, and i'm trying to check the value with console on functions it's just always say's undefined shit. So please help me ReactNinja's what actually is the wrong is going on here.

**Here codes you can have a look on them**

```
export default class EditNotes extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state ={};
    }


    handleEdit() {
        console.log(this + ' Clicked on That ');
    }

//Here it's throwing error when I'm trying to click and console. the problem is here. i want this.props.NotesAll value here also to finding elements from objects
    handleDelete(id) {
        let Notes = this.props.NotesAll;
        console.log(Notes)
    }

    render() {
        let noteItems;
```

//this.props.NotesAll working fine here.

```
        if (this.props.NotesAll) {
            noteItems = this.props.NotesAll.map( Note => {
                return(
                    <li key={Note.id}>{Note.body}
                    <button onClick={this.handleEdit.bind(Note.id)} className="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Edit</button>
                    <button onClick={this.handleDelete.bind(Note.id)} className="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Delete</button></li>
                    );
            });
        }
        return(
            <div className="col-md-4">
                <h3 className="header-ttile">Current Notes:</h3>
                <ul className="note-item-wrapper">
                {noteItems}
                </ul>
            </div>
            );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define the binding in a wrong way, first parameter will be the context to which you want to bind.

Use this:

```
<button onClick={this.handleDelete.bind(this, Note.id)}
```

**[Syntax:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind)**

```
fun.bind(thisArg[, arg1[, arg2[, ...]]])
```

**thisArg:**

> The value to be passed as the this parameter to the target function
>   when the bound function is called.

Comment: We don't have any issue with that, that is working perfectly.

Comment: I just need to have all the objects of `this.props.NotesAll` on handleDelete and handleEdith both place. it's throwing undefined.@Mayank

Comment: write it in the same way i suggested, because when you bind `this` then only you will be able to access the correct `this` (context) inside `handleDelete` method.

Comment: Oh Man, Are you kiddin me? It's working Holy @!!! Thanks man. I was just messing with it since 3 hours.

Answer (score 0):

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state ={};
    this.notes = props.notesAll;
    this.handleDelete = this.handleDelete.bind(this);
}
```

And then try to access your this.notes inside your handeDelete function. I'm not sure because I'm not a react ninja neither, but I think it should work this way